# What does 'set breadcrumb' do in Rules?

Tags: rules, breadcrumbs, actions

One of the actions that comes with the Rules module is 'set breadcrumb'.

[image: An example of a "set breadcrumb" rules action]

When trigger this action, however, nothing seems to happen to the breadcrumb.

What is supposed to happen? Does it set the breadcrumb on the page that the user was on when it was triggered, or on the page whose path is used in the action? Why isn't it doing anything, or is it doing something, and if so, what is it doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the "Set breadcrumb" rules action you should add it to the event "Content is viewed", for example

1. Event: Content is viewed
2. Condition: Content is of type article
3. Action: Set breadcrumb: Title: Articles\n[node:title] Paths: articles\n[node:url]

[rules_action_breadcrumb_set](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/rules_action_breadcrumb_set/7) basically goes through those title and path values and uses [drupal_set_breadcrumb](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_set_breadcrumb/7) to set the breadcrumb.